# SXA OOTB Social Share Heading Tag

Tags: sxa, socialshare

I am using SXA 9.3 with my Sitecore 9.3 instance.

For the Social Share component, there is a model property *HeadingTag* in the view file(snapshot attached below) for which there is no field shown in the Social Media templates.
[image: view file]

On dev tool inspection, it is clearly visible that there is a  tag but not sure how and where to add the value as there is no field.
[image: inspect]

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bug to me where in the existing Social Media Buttons template there is no field for Title.

- But you can simply create a new template inheriting   `/sitecore/templates/Feature/Experience Accelerator/Social/Settings/Social Media Buttons` and can add a new field for `Title`.
- After that, create a new item under `/sitecore/content/HBCS/IntranetHub/Settings/Social Media Groups` based on the new template and create social media items under this folder.
  [image]
- Now if you'll use this Social media share component on expedience editor, you'll see and edit the title.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Raman, yes it's a bug.
I did the same thing with the new template and adding the new field.
Thank you for the solution.